# Is there a difference in gnocchi between baking, steaming, or boiling potatoes?

Tags: baking, potatoes, boiling, steaming, gnocchi

I’m looking to make gnocchi. Lydia Bastianich says in her cookbook that we should boil the potatoes. Bryan Talbot says that we should bake them with a little bit of salt.

Comment: When you boil a potato, you don't dehydrate it as much as if you had baked it. Your recipe isn't just how the potato is cooked, you also have to consider what is mixed in, type of potato and the rest of the preparation. Try different recipes and see what you like. You do want a [dry, starchy potato for making gnocchi](http://www.seriouseats.com/2015/03/how-to-make-light-tender-potato-gnocchi.html). Gnocchi recipes are famously fiddly and fragile; if you want something a bit more foolproof, try a ricotta gnocchi.

Comment: What potatoes should I avoid?

Comment: The link I provided discusses that you can make good gnocchi with a variety of potatoes but you want to go for something Russett like, at least initially.

Answer (score 5):

There are several styles of gnocchi.  For potato gnocchi, use starchy, russet potatoes.  Boiling, steaming, or baking will all work.  I prefer baking, as it is easier to control the moisture content when mixing with eggs and flour.  Pass your cooked potato through a ricer or food mill before adding eggs and flour (though some folks use a fork and like rustic, small chunks of potato.) Try to avoid over-mixing for the lightest gnocchi.  Avoid waxy varieties.